# What is an example of a loss function that is not minimized by the conditional expectation?

Tags: loss-functions, conditional-expectation, decision-theory

From statistical decision theory we know that if we want to minimize EPE (Expected prediction error) it is sufficient to minimize the conditional expectation of the loss function.

$f(x) = argmin_{c} E_{Y \vert X}(L(Y, c) \vert X = x)$

For square loss $L(Y,c) = (Y-c)^2$ the solution is the conditional expectation $c=E(Y \vert X=x)$.

What is an example of a loss function that is not minimized by the conditional expectation? What is it minimized by? It would be great if the example were a loss function that is actually used to some extent and not totally contrived, but everything is welcome.

I think the property of a loss function being minimized by the conditional expectation is known as being p-admissible.

Answer (score 4):

If the loss function was for example $L(Y,c)=|Y-c|$

then the conditional *median* would minimise it

i.e. $c$ such that $\mathbb P(Y \le c\mid X=x) \ge \frac12$ and $\mathbb P(Y \ge c\mid X=x) \ge \frac12$

Comment: Extending this, we could use any of the (other) quantile regression loss functions so that the conditional mean does not optimize the loss, even when the error term is symmetric.